# PHP Searchfunction doesn't for some products but DOES work for others

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create searchfunction in PHP/MySQL. It works for some products but not for others. I can't figure out why that is the case.

I'm using the fields 'Product naam' and 'Merk' from this table: http://piclair.com/data/4192d.jpg

The searchfunction DOES work for searchquery's like 'cohiba' or 'punch'. But it doesn't work for searchquery's like 'sigarillos' or 'aansteker'. Also, when no product is found, it doesn't show an error message and I don't know why.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
         <?php 

         $invoer = $_POST['zoekwoord']; 

         ?>         

        <a href="index.php">Home</a> / <a href="zoekresultaten.php" class ="selected"><?php echo $invoer; ?></a>

    <?php
    //verbind met database
        include("login/con1.inc");


    $page=$_GET["page"]; //Get the page number to show 
    If($page == "") 
    {
      $page=1; //If no page number is set, the default page to 1 
    }

    //eerst wordt de query opgehaald om te bepalen hoeveel pagina's nodig zullen zijn.
    $sql = "SELECT '".$invoer."'
            FROM product                    
            ORDER BY productnaam";    // dit is dus de query om de producten op te halen

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()."<br>in file ".__FILE__." on line ".__LINE__); // als de query niet uitgevoerd wordt geeft die een foutmelding met bestandsnaam en regelnummer
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query); // Het aantal producten

    $Limit = 6; //Number of results per page 
    $NumberOfPages = ceil($Num/$Limit);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE merk='".$invoer."' AND Categorie_Nummer = 1 ORDER BY productnaam LIMIT " . ($page-1)*$Limit . ",$Limit") or die(mysql_error()); 



    if(empty($num)) {
                      echo "<p>Er zijn geen producten gevonden.</p>\n";
             } else {
                      // Laat de producten zien
                      while($product = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {                            
                      ?>

                      <table border="5" class="productlist" width="400px">
blablablabla
```

Hmm. While trying to create an error message I broke the searchfunction itself. Again it doesn't work for 'aansteker' etc. Also the error message doesn't work yet.

Here's the code I have now:

```
    <div id="contentbox">
         <?php 

         $invoer = mysql_real_escape_string($invoer);
         $invoer = $_POST['zoekwoord']; 

         ?>         

        <a href="index.php">Home</a> / <a href="zoekresultaten.php" class ="selected"><?php echo $invoer; ?></a>

    <?php
    //verbind met database
        include("login/con1.inc");


    $page=$_GET["page"]; //Get the page number to show 
    If($page == "") 
    {
      $page=1; //If no page number is set, the default page to 1 
    }

    //eerst wordt de query opgehaald om te bepalen hoeveel pagina's nodig zullen zijn.
    $sql = "SELECT productnaam LIKE '".$invoer."' OR merk LIKE '".$invoer."' 
            FROM product                    
            ORDER BY productnaam";    // dit is dus de query om de producten op te halen

    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()."<br>in file ".__FILE__." on line ".__LINE__); // als de query niet uitgevoerd wordt geeft die een foutmelding met bestandsnaam en regelnummer
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query); // Het aantal producten

    $Limit = 6; //Number of results per page 
    $NumberOfPages = ceil($Num/$Limit);

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productnaam LIKE '%$invoer%' OR merk='".$invoer."' AND Categorie_Nummer = 1 ORDER BY productnaam LIMIT " . ($page-1)*$Limit . ",$Limit") or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table (if that is the full table) has no records where `merk = 'sigarillos' OR mark = 'aansteker'` so the query will never return rows for those searches.  Perhaps you intend to search `productnaam as well.

Also, please remember to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to filter `$invoer` against SQL injection:

```
$invoer = mysql_real_escape_string($invoer);
```

To search for `productnaam` as well, change your query to the one below.  To get your error message showing, use `mysql_num_rows()` *after* the query above, rather than before it.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productnaam LIKE '%$invoer%' OR merk='".$invoer."' AND Categorie_Nummer = 1 ORDER BY productnaam LIMIT " . ($page-1)*$Limit . ",$Limit") or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Comment: Yeah. It seems like it only searches for 'merk' instead of both 'merk' and 'productnaam'.

But how do I change this? I search for * From the table 'product'. So 'productnaam' should be included in the search...

Comment: @Forza see the `LIKE` clause added above.

Comment: Ok, cool ;) That works. Only my error message doesn't display if I search for something that doesn't exist. Do you have any clue about that?

Comment: Hmm, this mysql_num_rows thing shouldn't affect the error message. Replacing it does nothing.

Maybe I can try to create an if statement for Mysql_error. I'll let you know if it works ;)

Comment: @Forza See also Tom's answer below. Your first query will have a syntax error.

Comment: I fixed that already ;) But I can't solve this error message problem. Everytime you want to code something that doesn't generate an error, but it does. And now I want an error, but I can't get one :) I will update my OP to reference the code that I have now. Will you have a look at it to see where the problem lies?

Comment: I changed the OP post for you ;) Thx for your help so far!

Comment: Lol, another student removed the entrys from the database that I used as searchquery :) I've tried nummerous queries now and it works great :P Only thing I changed from your answer to get it to work was changing productnaam LIKE '%$invoer%' into productnaam LIKE '".$invoer."' ;) I've marked your answer as accepted! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Forza the `%` in the `LIKE` clause are wildcards for partial matches, so you can search `Cigarillos` to return `Royal Cigarillos` rather than requiring the exact `Royal Cigarillos`